# how to remove small amount of space between two images

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

My code is just two vertically placed images:
[image]

but it outputs like this:

[image]

I tried \vspace{-1pt} and \vspace{-\lineskip} but both messed things up.  Does anyone know why this space is there?

Answer (score 3):

The `\lineskip` jumps in, because the second paragraph has a very big height.

For your application you may want to remove altogether the baseline business altogether.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}

\newpage

\noindent\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}\par\nointerlineskip
\noindent\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Note. I used `twocolumn` just for having the two picture combinations to appear side by side. Right is what you seem to want.

[image]